# Java JSoup: article extraction with image links and paragraph

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently making an article content extraction application using Jsoup and Java. My problem is when I scrape the article, Jsoup tends to return a list of Element rather than preserves the order of the article. For example, in an normal article with more than 1 image, it could has an order like this: (Title, sapo, image, paragraph, image, paragraph, paragraph, image, paragraph). So how can I scrape the main content of the website (text and image links) without losing its order?
Below is my idea for doing that but it doesn't work.

```
int cur = 0;
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div");
for (Element element : elements) {
    if (element.select("div[type=\"Photo\"] img").hasAttr("src")) {
        Elements temp = element.select("div[type=\"Photo\"] img");
        System.out.println(temp.get(cur).attr("src"));
        cur++;
    }
    System.out.println(element.select("p span").text());
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide a sample html page that you want to scrape and the desired output?

Comment: This is an article with video and some text: https://vnexpress.net/cuoc-hop-bao-dau-tien-cua-taliban-4342403.html,
This is an article with only text and images: https://vnexpress.net/nguoi-afghanistan-van-xep-hang-cho-di-tan-ngoai-san-bay-kabul-4342338.html

Comment: I try to design it so it could be able to scrap anything inside the main content of the article

Comment: What's *"sapo"*?

Comment: sapo can be considered as a description of that article that is used to attract readers to click that article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to extract the article data from the sites that you linked to in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780322/java-jsoup-article-extraction-with-image-links-and-paragraph#comment121639549_68780322), you could do something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

// Full article
Elements elements = doc.select("div.sidebar-1");

System.out.println("## Article title:");
System.out.println(elements.select("h1.title-detail").text());

System.out.println("## Article summary:");
System.out.println(elements.select("p.description").text());

// Images and paragraphs
for (Element e : elements.select("article.fck_detail p,figure")) {
    if (e.is("p")) {
        System.out.println("## Paragraph");
        System.out.println(e.text());
    } else {
        System.out.println("## Image (image URL)");
        System.out.println(e.select("img[src]").attr("src"));
    }
}
```

The idea is this one:

1. find the outermost container that contains the full article
2. extract title and the summary
3. loop through the image (`figure`) and paragraph (`p`) elements of the article - the order will be preserved automatically